# Python: Missing step in covariance matrix algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I wrote a method that returns a the covariance matrix of a given matrix, I think the code I wrote is missing some kind of normalization since the matrix I get back is exactly some constant times the matrix I get from np.cov()

```
import numpy as np
def calculate_covariance(matrix: np.array):
    mean_rows = np.zeros(matrix.shape[1])
    for rows in matrix:
        mean_rows += rows
    mean_rows /= matrix.shape[0]
    mean_matrix = []
    for _ in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        mean_matrix.append(mean_rows)
    mean_matrix = np.array(mean_matrix)
    subtracted_matrix = matrix - mean_matrix
    cov_matrix = np.dot(subtracted_matrix.T, subtracted_matrix)
    return cov_matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if you read the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html), you will find that `np.cov` by default divides by `N-1`.

Also, your code can be greatly improved by letting numpy compute the row means:

```
def cov(mat):
    # covariance of the *rows* of the given matrix
    rowmeans = mat.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    norm = mat - rowmeans
    return norm.dot(norm.T) / (mat.shape[1] - 1)
```

Comment: I got a negligible (3.3306690738754696e-16) difference between **calculate_covariance** and **np.cov** values if I remove `mean_rows /= matrix.shape[0]` at line 6 and instead divide by N-1 before returning cov_matrix : `return cov_matrix / (matrix.shape[0]-1)` . I guess this is the proper way to do it.